# Laravel verify if relation between many to many exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Using Laravel 5.5

Lets say I have a User table and Conversation table which are on a ManyToMany relation.

Users

id user

1  A

2  B

3  C

4  D

Conversation

id title

1 Conv1

2 Conv2

---

Users A, B and C are associated to Conv1

Users B, C and D are associated to Conv2.

If the user wants to create a new Conversation and chooses A,B and C

How can I verify that a Conversation with these and only these users already exists?

---

```
public function postThread() {
    $thread = new Thread;
    $thread->title = request()->get('name');
    $thread->type = request()->get('type');
    /* How to verify if Thread exists with and only with all the users in request()->get('users') */
    Auth::user()->threads()->save($thread); //creates relation with new thread
    foreach (request()->get('users') as $user) {
        $user = User::find($user);
        $user->threads()->save($thread);//creates relation with every user    with new thread
    }
    $thread->save();
    return $thread;
    }
```

Comment: Seems too broad , share code sample with specific question?

Comment: Haven't used Laravel in a while, and this is slightly off-topic, but doesn't `$user->threads()` query/connect to a DB? If so, running that in a loop might not be very performant, wouldn't you say? Couldn't you cache it like `$threads = $user->threads()` *outside* of the loop, and then do `$threads->save($thread)` *inside* the loop for performance gains?

Comment: You might be right, will look into it

Comment: let me understand, you want to check if there is a thread that associate with exactly the users you provide?

Comment: I think that there is no both elegant and effective solution for this. You can do this with somewhat sofisticated DB query.

Comment: Nevo: Exactly. So if there is already a thread with the users provided you won't create a new one and just return it.

Comment: Why you talk about conversations before and then the code is about threads?

Comment: @gbalduzzi because I asked a question in a way easy to understand, then I was asked for code I was using and the code I was using is conversation == thread but I didn't want to edit all the post into changing all Conversation into Thread because it is easier for people to understand what a conversation is. (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test it right now, but should work (still not very efficient)

```
$users = $request->get('users');
$user = Auth::user();
$validThreads = $user->threads()->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($users){
   foreach( $users as $user_id) {
      $query->where('user_id',$user_id);
   }
});
// Valid threads is a collection of threads where all the users are present, now we need to check that no more users are present in that thread
$totalUsers = count($users)+1;
$thread = $validThreads->filter(function($thread) use ($totalUsers){
    return $thread->users()->count() == $totalUsers;
})->first();

if (is_null($thread)) {
    // The thread does not exists
}
```

Comment: modified it a bit but the core worked. Thanks, as you and others said, not efficient and ugly but works.